# How to use ggplot to make a qqplot to compare the distribution of two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, quantile

I'd like to know how is possible to make a `qqplot` with **`ggplot2`** that compares two distributions and not a distribution to a theoretical distribution.
I want something like this:

```
qqplot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
```

that compares the quartiles of `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` in iris dataset, but using `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to reproduce the plot is to convert the `qqplot` call to a dataframe and then plot it with `ggplot2`:

```r
qq <- as.data.frame(qqplot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, plot.it = FALSE))
ggplot(qq) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]